# Calling a stateless lambda without an instance (only type)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to write a wrapper for a ["register callback" type of interface](http://orx-project.org/orx/doc/html/group__orx_command.html#gaabb6d028ab52dffb1c9bbfe3e75b9601) from a C library. The issue is quite complicated by the fact that, the library lets you register "variadic" functions by accepting a list of parameter definitions. Then at callback time, the function is expected to extract its arguments from a type-erased list of arguments. Good old C...

The interface I'm trying to create is to accept any function, even a lambda, and automatically generate all the machinery to correctly register this function, along with registering the arguments and extracting them during callback time. So the user should only have to type:

```
register_callback("Callback Name", [](int i){return i+0.5;});
```

Now this is theoretically possible, but at one point, I need to be able to call the lambda without any instance, but with access to only its type. I don't understand why, but the default constructor of a stateless (non-capturing) lambda is deleted, so I can't simply default-construct from its type. What I'm planning to do instead is a very dirty-looking, but should probably be OK way to work around this:

```
template <class Func, class RET, class ...ARGS>
struct from_stateless {
    static RET to_function(ARGS...args) {
        RET (*f)(ARGS...) = *(Func *)(0);
        return f(args...);
    }
};
```

so that `from_stateless<LAMBDA_TYPE, RET, ARGS...>::to_function` is actually a function pointer that I can call without an argument and more importantly one that I can pass as a TEMPLATE ARGUMENT.

Under normal circumstances, the line `RET (*f)(ARGS...) = *(Func *)(0);` would be suicide, but it really should be safe with this use case, isn't it? After all, the function pointer obtained after conversion couldn't in any universe possibly depend on the lambda instance.

So, the question is, is it safe to do this as long as I make sure that the type is indeed a stateless lambda? Or am I missing something? Note that the `RET (*f)(ARGS...) = *(Func *)(0);` would trigger a compiler error if a closure accidentally slips through.

CLARIFICATION: I can't just decay the lambda to a function pointer and register it, since the signature of the lambda is not compatible with the "Register" method. The register method expects a function with signature: `void (*)(int number_of_args, TypeErasedValue * arguments, TypeErasedValue * result)` So you see, I need to (and already do), through template metaprograming, generate a free function templated on the type of the lambda to act as an adaptor between the expected and the actual signatures.

Comment: The default constructor of a closure type is not deleted. There simply is none.

Comment: Also, should your "suicidal" line ever be executed, you'll invoke UB. I'm not saying this won't work on most implementations, but that the standard doesn't guarantee anything here.

Comment: This is quite similar to that trick Richard Smith has invented: http://pfultz2.com/blog/2014/09/02/static-lambda/ cc @Columbo (see also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf )

Comment: @Columbo It's quite reasonable that a closure is not default constructable, but the reason doesn't extend to captureless lambdas. About invoking UB, how will that line ever be executed? What can you do with the lambda to get a function pointer out of it? It's not like the C++ runtime will compile a new function at the call site.

Comment: @dyp Thanks a lot for the link, but I think I'm more comfortable with this implementation, since if this were compiled by a mad compiler so that it doesn't work as expected, it'll cause a clean Segfault, instead of doing random stuff on the stack.

Comment: Why do you believe a mad compiler would segfault on this code?

Comment: @Oktalist If the said compiler is going to do anything with the fake `Func *` we pass to it in `RET (*f)(ARGS...) = *(Func *)(0);` that would result in a SegFault.

Comment: What's mad about that? Seems like a very thoughtful and considerate compiler to me.

Comment: @Oktalist what's mad is that the compiler has no reason to touch that pointer.  The `f` in `RET (*f)(ARGS...)` is a pointer to a global function. How could the content of a stateless lambda instance in any way affect the function that it converts to? The compiler would have to be doing something mad to even try to read that address.

Comment: Whether or not the compiler touches the pointer is irrelevant. Don't try to second-guess UB. Any compiler, mad or not, can do anything with it. There's no UB in @dyp's comment.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to construct a lambda from it's type, instead of passing around the lambda that was passed in and storing it as appropriate?

Comment: @NirFriedman In effect, he wants to synthesize a `void(*)(void*)` which, when called, extracts values from its opaque pointer argument and passes those values as arguments to the lambda.

Comment: clang complains about dereferencing a (provable) null pointer. Going deeper into the UB, what I do is to take any address that is around to suppress the warning (preferably `this`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It gets even easier than @Yakk's answer if you take advantage of the fact that a lambda can see the `static` locals of its enclosing scope without needing to capture them. Using this fact you can wrap the user-provided stateless lambda in your own stateless lambda with the required signature, and convert the latter into a function pointer.

```
using callback = void (*)(int, TypeErasedValue*, TypeErasedValue*);

template <typename F>
callback stateless_to_callback(F f) {
    static F static_f = f;
    return [](int argc, TypeErasedValue* argv, TypeErasedValue* result) {
        // extract arguments from argv
        auto r = static_f( /* arguments... */ );
        // store r in result
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow, great answer, I didn't know about the ability to see `static` locals, this is a metaprogramming gem. Though I'm going to accept Yakk's answer since he provided the gist of the solution to the core problem.

Answer (score 4):

Want defined behaviour?

Add:

```
static Func state(Func* op=0){
  static Func f=*op;
  return f;
}
```

to your template class.  First time you call it, pass a ptr to lambda.  2nd time, extract value for free.

The `static Func f` is constructed the first time the function is called: so long as the pointer is non-null that time, we are good.  Every other time it is called, the pointer can be null and it does not use it, as `static` locals are only constructed once.

Call it to 'register' with pointer to lambda.  Elsewhere (at callback), call it to get a copy.  Lambda is stateless, so copy is free.

Comment: @enobayram naw, you should accept the best answer: and Oktalist's is better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something to register normal function

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
void register_callback(const std::string& s, Ret(*)(Args...))
{
    std::cout << "register function " << s << std::endl;
    // Implementation
}
```

You may simply explicitly convert your non-capturing lambda in pointer on function:

```
template <typename Lambda>
void register_callback(const std::string& s, const Lambda&f)
{
    // convert non capturing lambda into function pointer
    Register(s, +f);
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/06Cwhv)

or change your call site to something like:

```
register_callback("Callback Name", +[](int i){return i + 0.5;});
```

Note: You may use `*` instead of `+` for the decay.

Comment: If only it were this simple; I can't just decay and register my lambda, since the signature of the lambda is not compatible with the "Register" method. The register method expects a function with signature: `void (*)(int number_of_args, TypeErasedValue * arguments, TypeErasedValue * result)` So you see, I need to (and already do) generate an adaptor function through template metaprogramming.

Comment: I've thought long about this, and it's really a given of the problem that I call the lambda through its type, otherwise I can't generate a free function that adapts the incoming arguments and calls it.

Comment: @enobayram: So you have similar problem with functions which don't match the given signature.

Comment: it's not about just signature, really, the calling convention is very different. The C API tries to be able to call functions with variable number of arguments, so it exposes a type-erased interface. My purpose is to wrap this interface in a convenient and type-safe manner.