# Stateless lambdas as static local variable

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17

I am trying to write a templated wrapper class around a stateless lambda. Something like this:

```cpp
template <class TFuncOp>
class Adapter
{
public:
    void Op()
    {
        TFuncOp func; // not possible before C++20
        func();
    }
};
```

Since this isn't possible before default constructible lambdas arrive with C++20, I used this technique to make my class work: [Calling a stateless lambda without an instance (only type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681650/calling-a-stateless-lambda-without-an-instance-only-type)

So the final solution looks like this:

```cpp
template <class TFuncOp>
class Adapter
{
public:
    static TFuncOp GetOpImpl( TFuncOp *pFunc = 0 )
    {
        static TFuncOp func = *pFunc;
        return func;
    }

    void Op()
    {
        GetOpImpl()();
    }
};

template <class TFuncOp>
Adapter<TFuncOp> MakeAdapter(TFuncOp func )
{
    // Removing the line below has no effect.
    //Adapter<TFuncOp>::GetOpImpl( &func );
    return Adapter<TFuncOp>();
}

int main()
{
    auto adapter = MakeAdapter( [] { printf("Hello World !\n"); } );
    adapter.Op();
    return 0;
}
```

This code works on all major compilers (clang, gcc, msvc). But with one surprising discovery. Initialization (or lack thereof) of the static local instance of the lambda in GetOpImpl() has no effect. It works fine either way.

Can anyone explain how this works? Am I invoking UB if I use the static local instance of the lambda without initializing it?

Comment: Why does it have to be a lambda? Why can't you just make it a type with a name? It's not like you're using the most useful feature of lambdas (capturing variables). Just make it a named `struct` and move on.

Comment: Why does anything have to be a lambda? After all they are just syntactic sugar over a functor, and one can always write their own. Your comment is irrelevant to the question I asked.

Comment: The `Adapter` is not actually using the caller's `func` that is passed to `MakeAdapter()`. Why not simply have `Adapter` store the caller's `func` as a member, and then `Op()` can call it? Why does the `func` need to be `static` at all?  `template <class TFuncOp> class Adapter { private: TFuncOp func; public: Adapter(TFuncOp func) : func(func) {} void Op() { func(); } };` ... `template <class TFuncOp> Adapter<TFuncOp> MakeAdapter(TFuncOp func) { return Adapter<TFuncOp>(func); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, accessing a `nullptr` is never a good idea as it is UB.

But we can see that typical implementations generate code which simply works. I try to explain why:

First, it has nothing to do with lambdas. It is simply the not needed using of a copy constructor on a class which has no data. As you have no data, the generated code will not access the passed object. In your case, you "copy" the object which the pointer `TFuncOp *pFunc = 0` points to, which is a nullptr which will crash if the object must be accessed. As there is no data to access, a typical implementation will not genrate any code which will access the nullptr at all. But it is still UB.

The same works with all other types in the same way and has nothing special with a lambda!

```
struct Empty
{
    void Do() { std::cout << "This works the same way" << std::endl; }
    // int i; // << if you add some data, you get a seg fault
};

int main()
{
    Empty* ptr = nullptr;
    Empty empty = *ptr; // get seg fault here, because default copy constructor access the nullptr, but typically only if copy ctor needs to access!

    empty.Do();
}
```

And a lambda which has no captured data, is an empty structure with a `operator()()`.

That all is a answer *why* it seems to work.

Comment: Or, you know, the compiler could just optimize out the whole program and replace it to start advanced pyrotechnics.

Comment: "*...which will crash, if and only if...* You can't make statements like that if you dereference nullptr.

Comment: @cigien: there is nothing which can dereference a nullptr. If you try to copy an empty object, how you can access "something". Or I am wrong? How will the code for an manual generated copy constructor look like for an empty object?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but `*ptr` is just not allowed in the language. The compiler is not even obliged to generate any code for this program.

Comment: @cigien: " but *ptr is just not allowed in the language" ? You mean if it contains 0?

Comment: Yes, or `nullptr` as it is in your program.

Comment: @cigien: I am with you that it is UB, but I want to answer why it works. And what I also see is, that we can not write any code which will fail in this case if we manually write the copy constructor.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to describe what you think an implementation would do with such a program, but "...if and only if..." suggests that this is behavior that can be relied upon, and that simply isn't true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222429/discussion-between-klaus-and-cigien).